# dependent destroy failing when class_name is used

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a self referencing model that forms a tree structure. The nodes look like this:

```
class Node < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent, class_name: Node
  has_many :children, :dependent => :destroy, class_name: Node
end
```

When I try to destroy one I get the following:

```
Node Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "nodes".* FROM "nodes"  WHERE "nodes"."node_id" = ?  [[nil, 4]]
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: nodes.node_id: SELECT "nodes".* FROM "nodes"  WHERE "nodes"."node_id" = ?
```

I believe what is happening is that the pluralizer expects parent_id to be node_id (because of the class name). I don't know how to work around this.

### Edit

Model after applying answer:

```
class Node < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent, class_name: Node, foreign_key: :parent_id
  has_many :children, class_name: Node, foreign_key: :parent_id, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right with the issue, because you changed the name from `Node` to `:parent`, Rails will, by default, look for `node_id` instead of `parent_id`. In order to work around this, add `foreign_key: :parent_id`.

So the line should look like this:

```
belongs_to :parent, class_name: Node, foreign_key: :parent_id
```

Comment: Gave this a try and I seems to still be getting the same error. Other than editing that line is there anything I need to do? I tried restarting the server without effect.

Comment: Just took another look, seems as though this also needs to be done for `:children`

Comment: Yes, exactly you need to specify it on the `has_many` as well. Same key  `:parent_id`

Comment: That makes a lots of sense. I added foreign_key to children as well, and it allowed the delete.